# Unable to locate a Java Runtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio, консоль

Я пытаюсь проверить свою версию Java, установленную на MacBook Pro M1, я проверил несколько вопросов/ответов на SO, но все равно не работает

У меня установлена Android Studio, то есть Java точно установлена, но каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь выполнить любую команду относящееся к Java (например, java -version) получаю такую ошибку

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.

Что делаю не так?

**UPD**

В android studio JDK показывает тут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/check-java-version-on-mac-windows

Comment: https://santandergto.com/en/java-for-apple-m1-nightmare-arm-street/

Comment: у АС своя ява, ее в обычной консоли может и не быть

Comment: @Эникейщик как добавить?

Comment: на винде нужно добавить путь в переменную окружения PATH (его и при обычной установке явы надо добавлять, а то не будет работать, сам не добавляется). На маке не знаю, но, наверное, что-то похожее сделать

Comment: @Эникейщик ну вот да, я вроде попробовал по разному, но он все равно не видит ее

Comment: 1) указывайте полный путь до бинарника с java 2) либо проставьте JAVA_HOME

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 в итоге вторая ссылка помогла